# Loop through Object and show different keys

Tags: json, loops, object, key

```
var data = {
        "eventsHistory": [
            {
                "gameType": "RACE",
                "gameSubType": "HORSE",
            },
            {
                "gameType": "RACE",
                "gameSubType": "DOG",
            },
            {
                "gameType": "NORACE",
            }
            ]};
```

I have this structure. I want to show ALL gameType. But when there is a gameSubType, then only show this value and skip all gameType RACE.

For example: the result should be:
HORSE, DOG, NORACE

I can't find a way to show it correctly. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript has hasOwnProperty method to check if the key on an object exists or not

```
    var json = data.eventsHistory;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if (json[i].hasOwnProperty("gameSubType"))
      {
        console.log(json[i].gameSubType);
      }else {
        console.log(json[i].gameType);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var List = [];    
for (var i=0; i < data.eventsHistory.length; i++) {
    List.push(data.eventsHistory[i].gameSubType ? data.eventsHistory[i].gameSubType : data.eventsHistory[i].gameType)
}
console.log(List)
["HORSE", "DOG", "NORACE"]
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks